# Task inside and outside a loop

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task

I have two methods below. Can you please tell me what each method do in brief and how does the two methods differ from each other ?

```
 public void Method1()
{
        foreach (string symbol in arrList)
        {
           Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork(symbol));

        }
}

public void Method2()
{

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            foreach (string symbol in arrList)
            {
                DoWork(symbol);

            }
        });
}
```

Comment: You already have an answer - "Task inside and outside a loop". Can you please clarify what you don't understand? Especially after reading documentation on `StartNew`?

Comment: Will method2 create separate task for each for-loop or no ??

Comment: @user3447602 How many times is DoWork() called in Method2 (inside the loop) and how many times when you just made a single call? If you can answer that you have the answer to your question.

Answer (score 3):

The first will create many asynchronous Tasks that each call DoWork with the given symbol. The second will create one asynchronous Task that will do the entire loop before exiting.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to know if all the tasks in the first method got completed ?

Comment: @user3447602 Sure, collect them in a list and pass them to `Task.WhenAll`.